# Recoll - how to exclude indexing everything, then I'll add only a couple back in

Tags: recoll

How do I set Recoll to exclude everything? I will then add a small number of directories. But I mostly want it to NOT index most of the computer.

I currently have the default excluded directory in Skipped path:

/media

And I have 2 folders in Top directories (which I understand will overwrite anything in the Skipped path):

/home/mary/Mango

/home/mary/Pineapple

I want to have all of the rest of the computer NOT be indexed.
What would I add to the Skipped path to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: If you do not get adequate answers here, please check out Recoll's support website: https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/support.html

Answer (score 1):

In recoll, you configure starting directories. So if you just want to index two of them, specify them as starting directories.

See topdirs in [official documentation](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/webhelp/docs/RCL.INSTALL.CONFIG.RECOLLCONF.WHATDOCS.html):

> Parameters affecting what documents we index
>
> `topdirs`
>
> Space-separated list of files or directories to recursively index. Default to
>   `~` (indexes `$HOME`). You can use symbolic links in the list, they will be
>   followed, independently of the value of the followLinks variable.
>
> [ . . . ]
>
> `followLinks`
>
> Follow symbolic links during indexing. The default is to ignore symbolic
>   links to avoid multiple indexing of linked files. No effort is made to avoid
>   duplication when this option is set to true. This option can be set
>   individually for each of the 'topdirs' members by using sections. It can not
>   be changed below the 'topdirs' level. Links in the 'topdirs' list itself are
>   always followed.

It's also in the GUI under "Preferences" -> "Index configuration".

[image: Recoll - Index Settings]

Comment: I did have that set. The other day, I had upgraded to the new version. Now, in looking at Recoll, it is now "taking" the topdirs I had set, and has skipped indexing the whole computer. I guess in the older version it did not work properly, but in the new one that is working.